# Files on the ftp server are not showing up on html site

Tags: html, ftp

I've been uploading files to my site successfully up until now. Unfortunately I've been encountering this inexplicable error.

File and edits that show up in the files in my ftp server, are not showing up on my website.

What's happening!

Comment: Have you checked permissions on the files?  Maybe the are not available to public users?

Comment: Do you have any more information?  Please put absolutely everything you know about the problem into the question.  What have you tried?

Comment: +1 to Surreal Dreams because that's what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First, double check that you are naming the new/updated files exactly as they are named in the code for your site. It's possible that you are adding files to the server but your current code is linking to pages or documents with the previous names/spellings, not your new files. Second, are you using a client such as FileZilla to upload these files to the ftp server? If so, be sure to check that you are transferring the local files in the queue to the server after they have been added.  Additionally, you could try clearing your browser history. Perhaps your browser is using an outdated, cached version of your site.

Comment: Yes thank you for your help. I discovered that that I was reloading a cached version of my site. It was necessary to quit chrome. Is there a better way to clear my cache?

Comment: In chrome, going to settings>history (equivalent to pressing ctrl+H) and clicking "Clear all browsing data..." will give you the option to empty the cache.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to clear my cache?

Yah, most easy way is to use CTRL + F5 combination.
This works in most cases and order browser to reload CURRENT page, not from cach, but from the Internet